# Python Tkinter Lambda Multiple Variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick question. I have created a button like this:

```
LABEL = tkinter.Button(top, text ="GO 1", command = lambda *args: go('1'), width = 13, height=2)
```

So, I was wondering. How can I pass multiple values to definition using lambda in the button above?

```
def go(value):
```

Thanks!

Comment: You question is unclear. The command callback does not accept argument. What arguments do you want to pass to it?

Comment: `lambda x = "1": go(x)`, Multiple type arguments are not supported (just one)! So `go(list,str,str,int)` never work, and all type definitions is uniterable(just use event or tag).

Comment: @dsgdfg: your comment isn't true. You can use multiple arguments with `lambda`.

Comment: True, but that depends on the condition. If an element is not in global reach (created by iteration), it is necessary to give it a single argument or use the tag name as a variable. As the number of arguments increases, probability and combinations also increase, which significantly extends the writing of code, causing additional performance loss (response time, system resources, etc.). @BryanOakley

Comment: @dsgdfg: yes, more arguments == more complexity. However, you said it was impossible. It's not impossible.

Comment: the easy way is not the right way (always). The write code this thought causes excessive confidence in yourself. each "if" the requirement of 50 micro second delay if we admit (my own computer), it causes serious performance loss to be flexible. This leaves the impression that the performance of that bad Tkinter. Multiple error checking of arguments is difficult. This operation in an interface that is their inner loop do overall "disappointing". My "impossible" and by using the term: to overcome the problems that will occur in the future is necessary. Killing yourself is not part of freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put values in function call:

```
LABEL = tkinter.Button(top, text ="GO 1", command=lambda: go('1', 'a', True))
```

Then unpack the values in the function definition:

```
def go(*values):
    print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a tuple or a list like this:

```
def go(value):
    for val in value:
        print(val)
```

Create the button like this:

```
LABEL = tkinter.Button(top, text ="GO 1", command=lambda: go(('1', 'a', True)))
```

Or like this:

```
LABEL = tkinter.Button(top, text ="GO 1", command=lambda: go(['1', 'a', True]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a tuple and use it as a normal variable so you can add two or more variable in one tuple and transfer them with button:

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code or links to images of code, embed the code in your answer.